# Customized validation messages not working?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Am trying to add custom validation messages to this form, but cannot figure it out for the life of me..
Any help/advice is appreciated...thank you.

I have tried a few tutorials, but nothing seems to be clicking for me, I am sure its something simple, but I just cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks

FORM FOR THE VALIDATION:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
  require_once('connection.php');
  $OK = false;
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO students (studentTitle, studentFirstName, studentLastName)
      VALUES(:studentTitle, :studentFirstName, :studentLastName)';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':studentTitle', $_POST['studentTitle'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':studentFirstName', $_POST['studentFirstName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':studentLastName', $_POST['studentLastName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  $OK = $stmt->rowCount();

  if ($OK) {
  header('Location: http://localhost/mysqlquiz/student.php');
  exit;
  } else {
  $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
  if (isset($error[2])) {
    $error = $error[2];
    }
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add Student Details</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="header">New student details</h1>
<p><a href="student.php">Student Listing </a></p>
<?php 
if (isset($error)) {
  echo "<p class='warning'>Error: $error</p>";
}
?>

    <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$studentTitleErr = $studentFirstNameErr = $studentLastNameErr = "";
$studentTitle = $studentFirstName = $studentLastName = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["studentTitle"])) {
     $studentTitleErr = "A title is required";
   } else {
     $studentTitle = test_input($_POST["studentTitle"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["studentFirstName"])) {
     $studentFirstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $studentFirstName = test_input($_POST["studentFirstName"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["studentLastName"])) {
     $studentLastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $studentLastName = test_input($_POST["studentLastName"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
  <p>
      <label for="studentTitle">Title:</label>
      <select name="studentTitle" id="studentTitle" ><span class="error">* <?php echo $studentTitleErr;?></span>
            <option value="Mr">Mr.</option>
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="Ms">Ms.</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss.</option>
     </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="studentFirstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="studentFirstName" id="studentFirstName" ><span class="error">* <?php echo $studentFirstNameErr;?></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="studentLastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="studentLastName" id="studentLastName" ><span class="error">* <?php echo $studentLastNameErr;?></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add Details" id="insert">
    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear" id="clear">
    <input name="studentID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $studentID; ?>">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what *exactly* is not working in this code?

Comment: The custom error messages for when the user doesnt fill out the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code. you should check the validation first then insert.

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$studentTitleErr = $studentFirstNameErr = $studentLastNameErr = "";
$studentTitle = $studentFirstName = $studentLastName = "";

if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
  require_once('connection.php');
  $error = $OK = false;

  if (empty($_POST["studentTitle"])) {
     $studentTitleErr = "A title is required";
$error = true;
   } else {
     $studentTitle = test_input($_POST["studentTitle"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["studentFirstName"])) {
     $studentFirstNameErr = "First name is required";
$error = true;
   } else {
     $studentFirstName = test_input($_POST["studentFirstName"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["studentLastName"])) {
     $studentLastNameErr = "Last name is required";
$error = true;
   } else {
     $studentLastName = test_input($_POST["studentLastName"]);
   }
if($error == false)
{
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO students (studentTitle, studentFirstName, studentLastName)
      VALUES(:studentTitle, :studentFirstName, :studentLastName)';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':studentTitle', $_POST['studentTitle'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':studentFirstName', $_POST['studentFirstName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':studentLastName', $_POST['studentLastName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  $OK = $stmt->rowCount();

  if ($OK) {
  header('Location: http://localhost/mysqlquiz/student.php');
  exit;
  } else {
  $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
  if (isset($error[2])) {
    $error = $error[2];
    }
  }
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add Student Details</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="header">New student details</h1>
<p><a href="student.php">Student Listing </a></p>
<?php 
if (isset($error)) {
  echo "<p class='warning'>Error: $error</p>";
}
?>

    <?php

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
  <p>
      <label for="studentTitle">Title:</label>
      <select name="studentTitle" id="studentTitle" ><span class="error">* <?php echo $studentTitleErr;?></span>
            <option value="Mr">Mr.</option>
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="Ms">Ms.</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss.</option>
     </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="studentFirstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="studentFirstName" id="studentFirstName" ><span class="error">* <?php echo $studentFirstNameErr;?></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="studentLastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="studentLastName" id="studentLastName" ><span class="error">* <?php echo $studentLastNameErr;?></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add Details" id="insert">
    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear" id="clear">
    <input name="studentID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $studentID; ?>">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly, can you please let me know what you changed? (just so I dont need to harass people on here again!!)

Comment: I have checked whether field is the blank or not.So i have put your validation code at the top.If blank I have set a flag $error = true. when this flag is false I have insert the value

Answer (score 0):

Because your DB insert operation runs first and has no checks for required field data in order to run or not. So, it runs, and on success it redirects and exits:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/mysqlquiz/student.php');
exit;
```

Which clears `POST` and your required field logic never gets run.